# Is there a test (like likelihood ratios) that shows whether a beta regression model with regressed precision parameter is a better fit?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio, beta-regression

The `betafit` package in `R` allows beta regressions to be fit with either a constant precision parameter (controlling the variance of the distribution about the estimated mean $\mu$) versus allowing the precision parameter to be conditional on predictors. In one analysis I obtain a log-likelihood of 10000 vs 10500 without, and with regression for precision. How do I know whether allowing the precision to vary helped?

What I am looking for is essentially something similar to whether one should choose a Poison regression or negative binomial regression, for which, one test is to use the likelihood ratios: [Compare poisson and negative binomial regression with LR test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127505/compare-poisson-and-negative-binomial-regression-with-lr-test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood ratio test applies here and is covered by the betareg [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf). The reason why it applies is that default which fixes the optimal precision parameter is equivalent to regressing the precision parameter against a constant, compare:

```
library(betareg)
data(GasolineYield)
gy_logit <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
gy_logit_explicit_const <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp | 1, data = GasolineYield)
gy_logit2 <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp | temp, data = GasolineYield)
```

with relevant excerpts from their summaries:

```
summary(gy_logit)
Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(phi) 440.2784   110.0256  4.0016 6.2916e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 84.79756 on 12 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9617312


summary(gy_logit_explicit_const)
Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
             Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 6.0874072  0.2499001 24.35936 < 2.22e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 84.79756 on 12 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9617312


summary(gy_logit2)
Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
               Estimate  Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 1.364088821 1.225781237 1.11283    0.26578    
temp        0.014570318 0.003618285 4.02686 5.6527e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 86.97707 on 13 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.951863
```

Apart from the difference in the link function there is no difference between the parameter fitted using the default arguments or supplying a constant regression term explicitly.

Thus, applying the likelihood ratio test to see whether `gy_logit2` is a better fit than `gy_logit`:

```
1 - pchisq(2 * 86.98 - 2 * 84.80, 13 - 12) # 2 * diff in ll is chisq distributed
```

produces a p-value of `0.03679230527`.

This test does not need to be done manually as one can call the `lrtest` function from the `lmtest` package, as described in the vignette:

```
> lmtest::lrtest(gy_logit, gy_logit2)
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: yield ~ batch + temp
Model 2: yield ~ batch + temp | temp
  #Df    LogLik Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1  12 84.797558                        
2  13 86.977065  1 4.35901   0.036814 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```